# Delete all values matching index with less than N occurrences in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe indexed by an item_id, with varying numbers of rows per item (that is, item_id X might have 10 rows, while item Y might have only 1). What I want to do is delete from the dataframe all rows corresponding to those item_ids with only one row (i.e. remove all the items with only one observation). So, if a sample of the dataframe looked like this:

```
item_id measure1    measure2 ...
1       someNumber  someNumber
1       someNumber  someNumber
1       someNumber  someNumber
2       someNumber  someNumber
3       someNumber  someNumber
3       someNumber  someNumber
4       someNumber  someNumber
5       someNumber  someNumber
5       someNumber  someNumber
```

The new dataframe should look like this:

```
item_id measure1    measure2   ...
1       someNumber  someNumber 
1       someNumber  someNumber
1       someNumber  someNumber
3       someNumber  someNumber
3       someNumber  someNumber
5       someNumber  someNumber
5       someNumber  someNumber
```

That is, I want to remove all data for items with only one observation (in this case, item_ids 2 and 4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `groupby` and `filter`:

```
>>> df.groupby("item_id").filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
   item_id    measure1    measure2
0        1  someNumber  someNumber
1        1  someNumber  someNumber
2        1  someNumber  someNumber
4        3  someNumber  someNumber
5        3  someNumber  someNumber
7        5  someNumber  someNumber
8        5  someNumber  someNumber
```

In fact, this is very similar to one of the examples in [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html#filtration).

---

Note that, after some discussion in the comments, it became clear that in certain circumstances this doesn't seem to work in 0.12, but does in current trunk.  I believe this was fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/commit/e47e981f0a72b595e7bdce5e65acee125970e1e4) by jreback, which if I'm reading right branches on the type of the filter result, and thus avoids the difficulty.

Comment: This is close enough for me to accept, but it looks like you have to specify a particular column for this to work in cases where there are multiple columns, i.e. `df.groupby("item_id").filter(lambda x: len(x.arbitraryColumn) > 1)`. Otherwise you end up with an error like "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Comment: .. I'm confused.  There are multiple columns in the above example.  Are you saying that if you use exactly the line above with your frame, that's the error you see?

Comment: Exactly. The example in the docs apparently works because it's really only operating on a single column (maybe?). The line I specified in my comment works, the one you gave gives the error I quoted.

Comment: Okay, now I'm really puzzled.  I copied and pasted the above right from the window, so it works for me.  What version of `pandas` are you running?  Maybe this is something that's been fixed recently; I'm running trunk, more or less (0.12.0-751-gbea5051).  [One reason I'm so puzzled is because the number of columns should have nothing to do with anything, the `len` here is giving the number of rows in the group.]

Comment: I'm not sure of my exact build, but I do have 0.12.0. To be clear, the example from the docs *does* work for me. The issue is with my data frame, which has 8 total columns and a 2-part hierarchical index.

Comment: I experimented a little bit with using a hierachical `MultiIndex`, to see if that was the issue, but I still couldn't reproduce the error.  Would you mind editing the minimum example that fails into your question?  For me, for example, if I take exactly the three columns that you showed, `.reset_index()` as usual, and then `groupby`, it works just fine.  :-/  So that must be too simple a case.

Comment: Here's a printout of a sample ipython notebook: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/625604/scratch.html

Comment: @moustachio: thanks.  It definitely works for me (see [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/z3ho4grrwd8pzvf/Untitled0.html)) and I think I can see what changed in the code to permit this.  [Aside: when I asked "Are you saying that if you use exactly the line above with your frame", I don't think "Exactly" was the right answer.  I'd have said instead "no, not exactly -- I'm using `groupby(level="item_id")`, because I have a MultiIndex, and you're not grouping on an index but a column")

Comment: Okay, I think I can see the commit which fixed this -- the part of the code which is giving you the error message has changed, and in a way which I think explains why it's working for me.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be an example of [this issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4447) which has been resolved for version 0.13. If you are working with an older version, try ``x.count()`` instead.

Comment: @DSM Fair point; I should have been clearer. Thanks for digging to the bottom of this!

Comment: @DanAllan x.count() has the same issue. (though, again, x.arbitraryColumn.count() *does* work)

Comment: Right. To use it on a DataFrame, you must choose a column, because the filter function has to return a single True or False.